# Pandas to_date returns NaT for all values in my date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I'm working with a dataframe that shows historical prices for electricity. I'm wanting to convert the 'Months' column to datetime. I'm using the `to_datetime` to do this. However, when I do this, all the dates return as `NaT`. Specifically, the dataframe goes from this:

```
    Month  ...    PEA
0  Oct-22  ...  0.249
1  Sep-22  ...  0.021
2  Aug-22  ... -0.048
3  Jul-22  ... -0.053
4  Jun-22  ... -0.032
```

to looking like this:

```
   Month  ...    PEA
0    NaT  ...    NaN
1    NaT  ...    NaN
2    NaT  ...    NaN
3    NaT  ...    NaN
4    NaT  ...    NaN
```

My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

inputpath='HistoricalPrices'

dataset=pd.read_csv(inputpath,sep=',', dtype={'a': str},low_memory=False)

print(dataset.head())

dataset = dataset.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)

dataset['Month']=pd.to_datetime(dataset['Month'], errors='coerce', format='%m-%y')

print(dataset['Month'].dtypes)
print(dataset)
```

The `to_datetime` does change the `Month` column from `object` to `datetime64[ns]` but all the values in the `Month` column return `NaT`. How do I fix this? Am I doing something wrong within the `to_datetime` function? I appreciate any help!

Comment: you specify a format of "%m%y", but I see a dash between the month and year in your data

Comment: I added a dash between %m and %y. Looks like it's still doing the same thing of returning NaT for everything.

Comment: %m expects numbers. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Yep, looks like that was the issue! The person below suggested replacing %m with %b, and this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this format:
format='%b-%y'

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks, @misterhuge!